# Trying to use edeliver to release a package but getting deps/exrm/mix.exs: No such file or directory

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, edeliver

I'm trying to use `edeliver` to try to deploy my package to my server,

Everything almost goes fine, then I get this error

```
-----> Authorizing hosts
-----> Ensuring hosts are ready to accept git pushes
-----> Pushing new commits with git to: xxx@xxx
-----> Resetting remote hosts to ac1bb1a41f8e7c03b7f4bcbf44fa3b0ab866fcfd
-----> Cleaning generated files from last build
-----> Fetching / Updating dependencies
-----> Compiling sources
-----> Detecting exrm version
cat: deps/exrm/mix.exs: No such file or directory

Failed to detect exrm version.

Please set EXRM_VERSION_MAJOR, EXRM_VERSION_MINOR and EXRM_VERSION_PATCH
in the console or the config file.

Detected '' as major,
         '' as minor
     and '' as patch version.
```

I've ran `cat deps/exrm/mix.exs` and It definitely does exist. Any information on how to fix this would be great thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you haven't included it in the applications in your local mix.exs. Make sure you have something like this:

```
  def project do
    [app: :xxxxxxx,
     version: "0.0.2",
     elixir: "~> 1.0",
     elixirc_paths: elixirc_paths(Mix.env),
     compilers: [:phoenix, :gettext] ++ Mix.compilers,
     build_embedded: Mix.env == :prod,
     start_permanent: Mix.env == :prod,
     aliases: aliases,
     deps: deps]
  end

  # Configuration for the OTP application.
  #
  # Type `mix help compile.app` for more information.
  def application do
    [mod: {Codepaths, []},
     applications: [:phoenix, :cowboy, :logger, :gettext,
                    :phoenix_ecto, :postgrex, :edeliver, :ja_serializer, :con_cache]]
  end
```

This could solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add exrm as a dependency to your project

`defp deps do
    [{:exrm, "~> x.x.x"}]
  end`